# Build single dataset from multiple tables in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ask which requires me to use views in the query from the data store. The built-in copy utility doesn't seem to like my query with inner joins. I know the query works because I tested it in my local SSIS. How can I build a dataset that joins 2 or more tables in ADF? I tried going to the advanced tab and referencing SqlDataReader with my query, but I can't figure out how to see a preview of the results. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. Hope you have figured out how to do this. 
The authoring UI has been updated and you don't need to use Advanced tab now. 
Go to the copy activity source tab, put your query in the query input box, and then press the Preview button, you will see the query results.[image]